# Click outside menu to close it

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here's my function,

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('.a').click(function () {
     var here = $(this).next('.b');
    if (here.is(":visible")) {
        here.hide();
    } else {
        here.show();
    }
    return false;
  });
});
```

So, whenever I click the button it opens a small tab on same webpage & whenever I click it again it closes it. But once I open the tab I can't close it by just clicking somewhere on webpage apart from tab. I have to click the button again to close it.

How can I close tab just by clicking somewhere on webpage also by on the button?

Comment: $('body').click and hide function in here

Comment: Couldn't you use `.blur()` ?

Comment: Another option is to keep an overlay div in your `body` (transparent div with z-index less than your menu's). Now, whenever you show your menu, show this div as well. Add a click handler to this div, which closes the menu.

Comment: @Unknown How can I use .blur()

Comment: @FerhatBAŞ How can I do that?

Comment: Nevermind, don't use `.blur()`. Sorry, I was thinking of something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On document click, the closest helps to check whether the tab has been clicked or not:

```
$(document).click(function (e) {
    if($('.b').is(':visible')&&!$(e.target).closest('.b').length){
       $('.b').hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: Working perfectly fine! Thank You Sir :)

Comment: Great! :)
To know more about how closest works, refer https://api.jquery.com/closest/

Answer (score 3):

I end up searching for this on almost every project, so I made this plugin:

```
jQuery.fn.clickOutside = function(callback){
    var $me = this;
    $(document).mouseup(function(e) {
        if ( !$me.is(e.target) && $me.has(e.target).length === 0 ) {
            callback.apply($me);
        }
    });
};
```

It takes a callback function and passes your original selector, so you can do this:

```
$('[selector]').clickOutside(function(){
    $(this).removeClass('active'); // or `$(this).hide()`, if you must
});
```

Nice, chainable, elegant code.

Answer (score 0):

You want to check for a click on the body :

```
$("body").click(function(e) {
  if(e.target.id !== 'menu'){
    $("#menu").hide();
  }      
});
```

`menu` would be the id of the menu.

If the body is clicked and the id of the div clicked doesn't equal that of the menu, then it closes.

Comment: It's closing the div whenever i'm clicking on the small tab itself not when clicking outside of it?

Answer (score 0):

Check this implementation

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('click','body, #btn',function(ev){
        ev.stopPropagation()
        if(ev.target.id== "btn"){
            if($('#modal').is(':visible')) {
                  $('#modal').fadeOut();
            } else{
              $('#modal').fadeIn();
            }
          } else {
            $('#modal').fadeOut();
        }
      });
});
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btn">
  Click Me!
</button>

<div id="modal" style="background-color:red;display:none;">
  BLA BLA BLA
</div>
```

Comment: When you click on the menu itself, it also closes, which shouldn't happen.

Answer (score 0):

To check if the clicked element is outside of a given container, i.e. a menu, we can simply **check if the event target is a child of the container**. Using JQuery -

```
$('body').click(function(e) {

    if ( 0 === $(e.target).parents('#container-id').length ) {

        /// clicked outside -> do action

    }

})
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to add a **click listener** to the parent element, like here:

```
    $('.parent-div').click(function() {
    //Hide the menus if visible
    });
```

Also because click events bubbled up from child to the parent,
you can exclude **the click on the child** element to get bubbled up and count as the parent click too. you can achieve this like below:

```
    //disable click event on child element 
    $('.child-div').click(function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
    });
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.